# Expected "fonts" to be a list of maps

Tags: flutter, flutter-font

I downloaded a [font](https://arabicfonts.net/fonts/noor-regular) and placed it in assets.

**pubspec.yaml**

```
fonts:
    - family: Noor Regular
      fonts:
        - asset:assets/fonts/noorehuda-Regular.ttf
```

**Error:**

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Expected "fonts" to be a list of maps.
```

Comment: I think your formatting is a little bit of. Please take a look at this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Answer (score 1):

```yaml
fonts:
    - family: Noor Regular
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/noorehuda-Regular.ttf
```

The formatting is incorrect. give a space b/w asset: assets/...